# Respuesta a Consulta de datos SQL en la misma pagina del formulario

Tags: php, ajax, get

gracias por su interes en la pregunta. Estroy realizando una consulta en un formulario y en la misma pagina mosrando la consulta, intentandolo. De esta manera, lo que recibo son el nombre de la columna de la basey abajo, los encabezados de la tabla. Que modificacion deberia hacer para recibir todo?. y solamente el encabezado de la tabla HTML
Gracias por su ayuda.

index.html

```
   <form method="post" name="form" id="form">
               <input id="edad1" name="edad1">
               <input id="edad2" name="edad2">
               <input id="hijos" name="hijos">
               <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono">
               <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
            <button type="submit">Consulta</button>
    </form>

<div class="resultado"></div>

 <script>
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get( "consulta.php", function(data ) {
      $( ".resultado" ).html( data);
    });
});    
    </script>
```

consulta.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type:application/json; charset:utf-8');
include_once "conexion.php";
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion= $objeto->Conectar();

$edad_1 = $_POST["edad1"];
$edad2 = $_POST["edad2"];
$hijos = $_POST["hijos"];


$consulta = "SELECT plan_nombre,precio_total FROM precios WHERE edad_1 = $edad_1  AND  
edad_2=$edad2 AND num_hijos =$hijos" ;
$resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
$resultado -> execute();
$data = $resultado->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


echo "
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Planes</th>
            <th>Precios</th>
        </tr>
    ";
foreach ($data as $plan){
     
        $plan_nombre = $plan['plan_nombre'];
        $precio = $plan['precio_total'];
    
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$plan_nombre</td>
        
            <td>$precio</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }

    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Plan    Precio

Planes  Precios

Comment: Incluye el codigo del formulario bro

Comment: Pues estás recibiendo el HTML completo, pero se lo estás poniendo dentro de un elemento con class `resultado` que no sabemos si existe. Ahora, la parte final de la pregunta no es muy clara. Recibir todo es?  Recibir solamente el encabezado... hablas de los `<th>`?

Comment: Estás enviando un encabezado para determinar el tipo de respuesta como JSON, sin embargo, devuelves código HTML. Además, estás haciendo la petición por GET y esperas recibir los datos en POST.

Comment: Diria que tienes un error tipográfico aquí: `$data = $resultado->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` pues no es `fetchALL`, sino `fetchAll` (al menos eso dice el [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php)).  Prueba a ver.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios. Los resolvi enviando por POST creando un objeto FormData y XMLHttpRequest. La presentacion de la tabla en la pagina de inicio, es igual a como era en consulta.php, al que no le edite nada ( salvo las LL por ll, igual no afectaba). Gracias